# How to stop mouse drag events from moving entire window? [cocoa]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I think this should be a very easy one, but I cant find the answer on the docs.

I want to stop mouse dragging events which are in (or start in) my custom nsview subclass from causing the window to be dragged around the screen. How can I tell the window to stay still so i can interact with the view instead of dragging the whole window around? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the matter of whether you handle `mouseDragged`, you may need to override `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` to return NO, or override `isOpaque` to return YES.

Comment: Thank you, mouseDownCanMoveWindow/isOpaque is exactly what I was looking for, not sure how i missed it in the docs

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `mouseDragged:` in your view. [As documented](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/mouseDragged:), NSView's implementation simply passes the message to the next responder, which means that it will end up hitting the window. (Why? See [“The Responder Chain” in the Cocoa Event-Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2).) Responding to the message yourself prevents that, as long as you don't call up to the superclass implementation.

Comment: I do implement mouseDragged, JWWalkers answers was the trick. thank you